# Tcpclient/Tcpserver Multithread

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcpclient, tcpserver

I try to create a multithreaded server for getting reports about the usage, but I can not make the client connect to the server.

Can you please have a look and explain to me why ? I do not want any piece of code!

[Here](http://pastebin.com/RTBsEJs9) is the server's communication layer and [here](http://pastebin.com/Ua3aqq2M) is the client's communication layer.

Thanks,

Daniel

Comment: Have you done unit tests on this code, i.e. tested each server and client in isolation? This would be a basic step before going any further.

Comment: Found the issue, I replaced IPAddress.Loopback with localhost and it worked. My new question is : Shouldn't IPAddress.Loopback, "127.0.0.1" and localhost be the same thing ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the client side. I resolved it by replacing "127.0.0.1" with "localhost".